# How can I convert DBNULL or Empty string to Double in one line of code?

Tags: c#, typecasting-operator

I wonder if there is a inline/single line way to convert a DBNULL or Empty String value to double or int in C#. I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

My example table

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |

This null value column might contain empty strings in some tables. Precisely, I want to convert empty string or NULL to Double.

I'm using ADODB.Recordset to retrieve data from the table.

I tried this line of code

```
Double v = Double.Parse((MyDataSet.Fields["Amount"].Value??"0").ToString());
```

This converts the NULL to double but if the result value contains an empty string, it shows an error

`input string was not in a correct format`

Now what I'm doing is this using ternary operator, I believe this is really bad.

```
Pseudo:
If value=="" then
  Parse double value
Else if Value==Null Then
  Parse Zero(0)
Else
  Parse Actual column value to variable
End if
```

Comment: Extension method

Comment: Why must it be a single line statement? You could just write a function which does the conversion and pass the value to the function, this in turn would be single line and shorter then your code above. Just create a `function` or `Func<object, int>` that does the job.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @Max. That is the best idea I could implement.